# SQL - How to Select Entries containing a Word through all Variations of Upper & Lower case for each Character of that Word?

Tags: sql, oracle

I work in a factory where we use a software to control the operation of the machines.
Sometimes, we need to deviate from the normal flow of the software 'recipes' - and we do this via what is called an 'unlock' or a 'bypass'.

When we select the option to do this in the recipe on the computer, a dialog box appear and prompts the user to type in what they are performing - an 'unlock' or a 'bypass'.

However, this dialog box is not case sensitive.

If we take the word 'Unlock' - and account for all Upper & Lower Case variations of each character in that word - that's 64 different ways of writing the word 'Unlock'.
(e.g. Unlock, unlock, UNLOCK, unlocK, UnLoCk, uNlOcK etc.)

**Is there any way for me to select all entries with the word 'Unlock' through all variations of case for each character in that word?**

Also:

- Is it possible to select all entries that have the Word 'unlocK' with an Uppercase 'K'? (Assuming the User always writes the 'K' as the last character of 'unlocK'.)
- Is it possible to account for an accidental space in the word 'unlock'. For example, if somebody types 'un lock'?

The Table in the Database is know as CO_EXCEPT_TEXT_LG and the Column name is called 'EXPLANATION'.